# Center and Bottom of Div

Tags: css, html, icons

I wish to center my font icon at the bottom of the div. I know that I could have it positioned absolute to the background and use bottom:0 but I can't get margin:auto to center it either side.

Here is my code:

```
    <section> 
       <p><i class="fa fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down"></i></p>
</section>

section {
background: url("../img/background.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
background-size: 100%;
background-color: black;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
}


section p i {
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-size: 15em;
    bottom:0
}
```

Comment: Have you tried left: 50%; ?

Comment: That would position it left 50% but from the start of the icon i.e. from the left side of the icon, not the icons centre position. That make sense? The icon would start from 50% of the page.

Comment: But then you adjust the left: to 47%, or 46% or you change the size of the icon, or the size of its container. Many different solutions. You could also put it in a 100% wide div, tacked to the bottom, with the icon centered.

Comment: I've since put it to 47.4% left (some minor calcs) but at the time thought their must be a much easier way... I'm very new to all this. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your icon is a text, so you can use the property `text-align: center;`.

A [jsfiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/6TbMs/). I made some modifications in the code.

html

```
<section> 
   <p><i>☺</i></p>
</section>
```

css

```
section {
    background: black url("http://placehold.it/420x150") no-repeat center center; // you can put the background-color here by the way
    background-size: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center; // magic stuff here !
}

section p i {
    position: absolute;
    color: red;
    font-size: 2em;
    bottom: 0; // you forget a ';' here
}
```

Is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: Thank you sir! I can't up vote your answer though :(

Comment: Do not have 15 reputation.
Can't see anywhere to mark it resolved either? Might be my ignorance though.